# Can not save file inside tmp directory

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function to save an image inside the tmp folder

```
private func saveImageToTempFolder(image: UIImage, withName name: String) {

    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
        let tempDirectoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(name).jpg").absoluteString
        print("target: \(targetURL)")
        data.writeToFile(targetURL, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

But when I open the temp folder of my app, it is empty. What am I doing wrong to save the image inside the temp folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`absoluteString` is not the correct method to get a file path of
an `NSURL`, use `path` instead:

```
let targetPath = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(name).jpg").path!
data.writeToFile(targetPath, atomically: true)
```

Or *better,* work with URLs only:

```
let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(name).jpg")
data.writeToURL(targetURL, atomically: true)
```

Even better, use `writeToURL(url: options) throws`
and check for success or failure:

```
do {
    try data.writeToURL(targetURL, options: [])
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not write file", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Swift 3/4 update:**

```
let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(name).jpg")
do {
    try data.write(to: targetURL)
} catch {
    print("Could not write file", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the URLs only option

Comment: Saved a lot of my time. I firstly used absoluteString but got nothing work. The key is """"""""""""path""""""""""""""". Thank you so much!

Comment: Get this error when trying to apply this code to caches directory. "Could not write file The file “jd64q7sc5n.png” doesn’t exist"

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to try to write directly to the complete FileManager() file path like so :

```
    let filePath = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(id).mp4")
    //You can choose a specific directory with FileManager.default.urls(for:in:)
```

before doing

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    do {
        try data?.write(to: filePath)
        //Write is a success
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        //Error while trying to write
    }
}
```