# Swift 3 Creating a folder throws error "file does not exist"

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to create a directory with the following code, but it thorws an error "file does not exits". Sure, it does not exist as I want to create it.

```
let dirName:String="test2"
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(dirName,isDirectory: true)

do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
       print("OK")
} catch let error as NSError {
      print("Error creating directory: \(error.description)")
}
```

Error:

```
Error creating directory: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4
"Le fichier « test2 » n’existe pas." (Translation: The file « test2 » does not exist)
UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C91525D0-04D2-47A3-BC00-E75D1B616A73/Documents/test2/,
NSUnderlyingError=0x12fee48c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

How to create a directory ?

Comment: `absoluteString` is the *wrong* method to use here, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310200/can-not-save-file-inside-tmp-directory.

Comment: Thank you, can you post the answer, so I can accept it?