# Path for resource returns nil file path despite file is in Documents directory

Tags: ios, swift, path, bundle, filepath

When I run this code and add a breakpoint:

```
var pathFor = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "png")
print("breakpoint added here")
```

I see a **nil** value for the **pathFor** variable.

However, if I contextually check the file existence in my app Bundle (using XCode -> Device -> Device Name -> Download Container -> Show package content), I can see it inside the **Documents** directory:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**:

I have modified the code, following the suggestion in the **answer**.

Unfortunately I am unable to instantiate an image based on the path.

Please see here:

[image]

Comment: Where are you adding the breakpoint exactly ?

Comment: At the print command

Comment: Can you try with "imageName" instead of imageName

Comment: Are you sure *imageName* is correctly spelled? Also, remember case-sensitivity matters, even for the file type. (I've had this happen to me before. PNG is different than png.)

Comment: `absoluteString` is almost *never* what you should use. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/39310200/1187415 for a similar issue. Use the `path` property or better, work with URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking inside the Bundle ( i.e.: files embed on compilation time ) for a file you put in the Documents Folder. that ain't gonna work.

Your file is here :

```
if let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true).first {
        if let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dir).appendingPathComponent("file.html") {
                print(path as Any)
                if  let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: path!) {
                     let image = UIImage(data:imageData as Data)

    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks! I have tried to apply your code to mine and I am unable to retrieve the image associated to that file path.. would you be able to double check my edit?

Answer (score 0):

Another permutation, but I'd personally do:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    .appendingPathExtension("png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
```