# Trouble fetching database path

Tags: swift, sqlite, filepath, local-database

Integrated SQLITE Database, below is my code which I have written,

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.copyDatabaseIfNeeded()
        return true
}

func copyDatabaseIfNeeded() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let dbPath = getDBPath()
    var success: Bool = fileManager.fileExists(atPath: dbPath!)
    if !success {
        let defaultDBPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath ?? "").appendingPathComponent(APPLICATION_DB).absoluteString
        success = ((try?fileManager.copyItem(atPath: defaultDBPath, toPath: dbPath!)) != nil)
        if !success {
            print("Failed to create writable database!")
        }
    }
}

func getDBPath() -> String? {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDir = paths[0]
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDir).appendingPathComponent(APPLICATION_DB).absoluteString
}
```

It always print below output,

[image]

- Tried clean + Build Project
- Uninstall the application, reinstall it
- Remove derived data

none of the above has worked.

Also, my sqlite file is there in project target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources : below screenshot for reference.

[image]

I am not sure whether hierarchy of my file matters or not, attaching screenshot of that as well.

[image]

Can anyone help me why I am getting issue in fetching file path of my database file?

Comment: did you add breakpoints to see the exception or the issue?

Comment: Yes I added breakpoints, first condition which is there is for checking file already exists or not so in that I am receiving false. Then again it is fetching path of my local database file from bundle, but again my boolean returns false. I don't know why. File is already there, then it should be true. @Shabirjan

Comment: The actual problem is that `absoluteString` does not what you think it does, compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310283 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/34135437.

Comment: @MartinR Perfect! Here you catch my mistake. This is want I was mashed up with. Actually I worked with SQLITE in objective-c and in that I had not face this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
func copyDatabaseIfNeeded() {
    // Move database file from bundle to documents folder

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                in: .userDomainMask)

    guard documentsUrl.count != 0 else {
        return // Could not find documents URL
    }

    let finalDatabaseURL = documentsUrl.first!.appendingPathComponent("SQL.sqlite")

    if !( (try? finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false) {
        print("DB does not exist in documents folder")

        let documentsURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("SQL.sqlite")

        do {
              try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: (documentsURL?.path)!, toPath: finalDatabaseURL.path)
              } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Couldn't copy file to final location! Error:\(error.description)")
        }

    } else {
        print("Database file found at path: \(finalDatabaseURL.path)")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is resulting in "DB does not exist in documents folder" :(

Comment: Plucking my hair by thinking what I am missing. As this is not the first time I am dealing with local database. But this time nothing is working somehow.. :(

Comment: Wait let me try that out.

Comment: I think your solution is working.. first it is executing "DB does not exist in documents folder" and then next time I am getting "Database file found at path:"

Comment: Yes thats what i am checking now.

Comment: So first time file is not there in documents folder, so this code moving file from main bundle to documents and then next time it is detecting that file is already there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciated. Thanks. :)